# List of AWS instances by TAG value using powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-powershell, aws-resource-group

We are taging our AWS instances, I will like to retrieve a list of ALL our instances (ELB, S3, EC2, Security Groups) by TAG reference. for instance we consistently TAG our resources with something like this:
        { "Key": "Project",
          "Value": "bananas"
          },

How can we obtain trough  power-shell a list of ALL our resources that contain the TAG Project value "bananas"?

I was able to get all my EC2s using the below script:

$instance = Get-EC2Instance 
   `-Filter @( @{name='tag:Project'; values="bananas"}; 
           @{name='instance-state-code'; values = 16} )`
   | Select-Object -ExpandProperty instances #Get instance ID ignoring any terminated instances
  $instance | Export-CSV "C:\ec2.csv"

But I'm not sure how to obtain all my tagged resources using one script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [AWS Resource Groups Tagging API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) cmdlets -- these are relatively new, so you may have to update your AWS Tools for PowerShell to the latest version to be able to use them.

### Example

The example below calls `Get-RGTResource` for the tag Key=Project, Value=Bananas, and filters the response to all ResourceARNs that were retrieved. The ResourceARN is a unique identifier for each AWS resource, and you can use these as a starting point to call out to other AWS services to get more details about each associated resource.

```
(Get-RGTResource -TagFilter @{Key="Project"; Values = @("bananas")}).ResourceARN
```

### Example Output

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:<accountid>:instance/i-abcd1234
arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:<accountid>:vpc/vpc-abcd1234
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-2:<accountid>:security-group/sg-abcd1234
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:<accountid>:loadbalancer/abcd1234
arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:us-east-1:<accountid>:cluster/abcd1234
```

### Further Reading

- [AWS Documentation - Get-RGTResource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-RGTResource.html)
- [AWS Documentation - Amazon Resource Names (ARNs)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)

Comment: Really useful info in your response. exactly what I was looking for, thank you Anthony!